# añadir columna "grupo" a un dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, pyspark

Necesito añadir una nueva columna al suigiente datafrtame en pyspark de manera que aquellas filas que tengan el mismo valor en la columna "column_1" deberán tener el mismo valor númerico, empezando por el 1 en una nueva columna llamada "grupo"

````
``` # +---+-------------+
# | id| column_1|
# +---+-------------+
# |  0|    a    |
# |  7|    a    |
# |  1|    c    |
# |  2|    d    |
# |  3|    e    |
# |  4|    a    |
# | 10|    c    |
# | 12|    b    |
# +---+-------------+```
````

Y quiero:

````
``` # +---+-------------+
# | id| column_1| grupo|
# +---+-----------------+
# |  0|    a    |  1  | 
# |  7|    a    |  1  | 
# |  1|    c    |  3  | 
# |  2|    d    |  4  | 
# |  3|    e    |  5  | 
# |  4|    a    |  1  | 
# | 10|    c    |  3  | 
# | 12|    b    |  2  | 
# +---+-------------+```
````

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código que tienes? ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Lo he logrado así:

```
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("aux").orderBy("column_1")
df_expl = df_expl.withColumn("aux", F.lit(1))
df_expl = df_expl.withColumn("group",dense_rank().over(windowSpec))
df_expl = df_expl.drop("id")
```

Comment: Por que este código resuelve tu duda? Podrías editar tu respuesta para que lo explique por favor?